# Angular 9 : Allow trailing slash with optional parameter value in routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

We have below requirement for optional parameter. Routing is not matching with current URL. There are different cases of Parameter value. Parameter value can be blank. What we can change in below routing code?

Below are the request URL cases.

```
http://localhost:4200/act/sso/app/2040/token/7d2f-4ddd-924f-3fd36572/address/chd/city/chd/state/chd/zip/94524/tax/1000/rep1/ianchi/rep1Email/ianchi@am.com/rep2/Ryan/rep2Email/raphael@am.com

http://localhost:4200/act/sso/app/2040/token/7d2f-4ddd-924f-3fd36572/address/pkl/city/phonix/state/ca/zip/90401/tax/600/rep1//rep1Email//rep2//rep2Email/

http://localhost:4200/act/sso/app/2040/token/7d2f-4ddd-924f-3fd36572/address//city//state//zip//tax//rep1/ianchi/rep1Email/ianchi@am.com/rep2/Ryan/rep2Email/raphael@am.com
```

I am using below code in app-routing.module.ts file.

```
{
    path: 'act/sso/app/:app/token/:token/address/:address/city/:city/state/:state/zip/:zip/tax/:tax/rep1/:rep1/rep1Email/:rep1Email/rep2/:rep2/rep2Email/:rep2Email', 
    component: SSOComponent
},
```

Please help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Parameter value can be blank

If that would be the case, use Angular's `Query Parameters` instead of `Router Parameters` -- With that, you need to send an object inside the URL which Angular will parse in.

Attached **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-query-params?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your reference

---

**Route**

```
{
    path: 'sso', 
    component: SSOComponent
},
```

---

**Template from another component**

```
<a [routerLink]="sso"
   [queryParams]="ssoParams">SSO</a>
```

or *inside it's component*

```
@Component({...})
export class OtherComponent {

  ssoParams = {
    app: 1,
    token: 123,
    address: 'random'
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {}


  // or you can also redirect it inside the component
  redirect(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['sso'], { queryParams: this.ssoParams })
  } 
 
}
```

When redirected, the url will now be:
`/sso?app=1&token=123&address=random`

If it's empty or if you have passed an empty value on those objects, the URL which angular will parse in will only turn to like this, which is still valid:
`/sso?app=&token=&address=`

---

**SSO Component**

```
@Component({...})
export class SSOComponent {

   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
     // fetch the query parameters via subscribe
     this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => console.log(params))

     // or to fetch the query parameters directly via object
     // which this will contain: {app: 1, token: 123, address: 'random'}
     console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams);
   }  

}
```

Comment: @Vin If it helps you, hope you can mark my answer as the accepted solution :) But if there's something that I have missed. Let me know :)